# Pass through multiple dbmodel to a view from a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.

I have this class:

```
namespace Attempt4.Models
{
    public class UsersModel : DbContext
    {
        public UsersModel()
            : base("name=UsersConnection")
        {
        }
       public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Roles> UserRoles { get; set; }
       public DbSet<UsersInRoles> UsersInUserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }      
}
```

Then there is another class:

```
public partial class FskWebInterfaceContext : DbContext
{
    public FskWebInterfaceContext()
        : base("name=FskWebInterfaceContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<trigger_dest_assoc> trigger_dest_assoc { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_AccessLevel> ut_AccessLevel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_Client> ut_Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_ContactID> ut_ContactID { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_destinations> ut_destinations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_DeviceDescription> ut_DeviceDescription { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_DeviceType> ut_DeviceType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_event_log> ut_event_log { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_GMUTempData> ut_GMUTempData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_Triggers> ut_Triggers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_User> ut_User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_UserAPNdevices> ut_UserAPNdevices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ut_UserClientLink> ut_UserClientLink { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to be able to access both of these database contexts from my view.
I know how to pass through just a model for example just UserProfile. But I need to be able to access all of the elements in these two classes.

How can i pass them through from the controller to the View.

And Specifically, once I have passed them through, how do I access them individually in the view?

Comment: From what I have been reading I need to make use of a ViewModel class.

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer in the comments section of your question:

> From what I have been reading I need to make use of a ViewModel class.

So go ahead and define a class that will contain the necessary information. Then in your controller action populate the properties of this model and have it passed to the view.

For example let's suppose that you wanted to access `UserProfiles` from the first context and the `ut_GMUTempData` from the second context:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public IList<ut_GMUTempData> GMUTempData  { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ctx1 = new UsersModel())
    using (var ctx2 = new FskWebInterfaceContext())
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.UserProfiles = ctx1.UserProfiles.ToList();
        model.GMUTempData = ctx2.ut_GMUTempData.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and now your view becomes strongly typed to the view model and you can access both properties:

```
@model MyViewModel
... you could use both @Model.UserProfiles and @Model.GMUTempData collections
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how you could loop through the user profiles in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@foreach (var profile in Model.UserProfiles)
{
    <div>@profile.SomePropertyOfTheUserProfileClassThatYouWantToDisplayHere</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Could You please elaborate on how I would then recieve and use it in the view>?  Must i use @model Ienumerable<>MyViewModel ? Could you please add a code spinner of a view where you just do a for each statement for userProfiles.